# How to test a small kernel in a VM?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, virtual-machine

Say I developed a small kernel and I wanted to try it out in a VM.

If I have the kernel image, how would I get it into a VM in VirtualBox, for example? More importantly, how do I get a bootloader like Grub installed into the VM?

Comment: The vote to close says "belongs on serverfault".  I don't think it belongs on serverfault at all.

Comment: @Kib: I think someone saw the `virtual-machine` tag and just didn't read the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way might be to install some version of Linux, and then edit your grub config files to add in your own kernel,  Add it as another boot option.

Comment: Is there a small easy-to-install distro that would be good for this?

Comment: Damn Small Linux is probably about the smallest mainstream distro out there.  I don't think it would be that difficult to install.

Comment: You could actually just boot your VM from an image of a Linux live cd (any one that has grub would do) and use that to install grub onto the VM's hard disk.